# update causing pagination to fail on comments in panel page template

Tags: panels, updating, chaos-tool-suite

I recently was alerted to an issue on a website I'm in charge of in which the correct comments were not being shown. I dug into the issue and noticed that it was actually an issue with pagination of the comment pages. Basically what is happening is the comment pages are not advancing when clicking on the next page (so mysite.com/blog/post?page=1 won't actually take show the second page of comments, rather just the first page).

I have a few different dev versions of this site, and when testing on one that had a few updates needed to it, I noticed the issue didn't exist on that site. Upon updating ctools and panels I noticed the issue started to show up on this dev site as well.

I'm not doing anything overly special in the panel pages node template, just using node being viewed comments that comes with panels (under add content, node, node comments). Not sure what would be causing the issue, or why it would fail after an update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this was an issue with ctools that was introduced into version [7.x-1.6](https://www.drupal.org/node/2415979). The bug in question was introduced in the patch for [Update node_view.inc to execute the normal Drupal hooks](https://www.drupal.org/node/1760384).

Luckily, there is a patch of that patch, which can be found at [Entity-related hooks can be redundantly invoked for same entity in certain situations causing errors.](https://www.drupal.org/node/2422123)